# How to average gdal_hillshades?

Tags: gdal, dem, hillshade, gdal-calc

For some unknow reason, my average of 3 hillshades is very dark :

```
gdaldem hillshade input.tif hillshades_C.tmp.tif -s 111120 -z 5 -az 315 -alt 60 -compute_edges
gdaldem hillshade input.tif hillshades_B.tmp.tif -s 111120 -z 5 -az 355 -alt 60 -compute_edges
gdaldem hillshade input.tif hillshades_A.tmp.tif -s 111120 -z 5 -az 275 -alt 60 -compute_edges
gdal_calc.py -A hillshades_A.tmp.tif  -B hillshades_B.tmp.tif -C hillshades_C.tmp.tif --outfile=./hillshades.tmp.tif --calc="(A+B+C)/3"
```

[image]

I did tried `--calc="(A+B+C)"`, it get lighter, but still too dark and not as expected.

Answer (score 4):

For my case (hillshade and my computer), I had to use `--calc="(A/3+B/3+C/3)"` to get a correct average results.

`(A+B+C)/3` fails because gdal_calc limit the equation to a [0-255] range. `(A+B+C)/3` will first calculate `A+B+C modulo 256`, then divide this value (in range `[0-255]`) by `3`, giving a low value and dark output.

For more on gdal_calc operators, see [How does gdal_calc numpy operators work?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146689)