# How to create composite hillshade?

Tags: gdal, dem, hillshade, gdal-calc

The concept of **composite hillshade** is to combine multiple hillshades with different sunlight orientation to avoid blind spot. It requires to merge 3 hillshades images with 315⁰ (NW sunlight, default layer), +355⁰ layer, +275⁰ sunlights, respectively. This increase details and elegance, as shown below.A full non-GIS [description is here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia:Graphics_Lab/Resources/Optimizing_shaded_relief_using_GIMP_(old)&oldid=661115748#Composite).

[image]

Using any srtm file, the 3 initial hillshades can be done via :

```
gdaldem hillshade input.tif hillshades_A.tmp.tif -s 111120 -z 5 -az 315 -alt 60 -compute_edges
gdaldem hillshade input.tif hillshades_B.tmp.tif -s 111120 -z 5 -az 355 -alt 60 -compute_edges
gdaldem hillshade input.tif hillshades_C.tmp.tif -s 111120 -z 5 -az 275 -alt 60 -compute_edges
```

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24798/19460

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The linked source mention ***"change its fusion mode to < Multiply >"***, so the operation to do is not a simple average of input hillshades (for this, see also [How to average gdal_hillshades?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146292/)). It's something else. Yet, let's create the 3 different-sunlight-directions hillshades :

```
gdaldem hillshade input.tif hillshades_A.tmp.tif -s 111120 -z 5 -az 315 -alt 60 -compute_edges
gdaldem hillshade input.tif hillshades_B.tmp.tif -s 111120 -z 5 -az 355 -alt 60 -compute_edges
gdaldem hillshade input.tif hillshades_C.tmp.tif -s 111120 -z 5 -az 275 -alt 60 -compute_edges
```

[image]

#### **Keep lowest value of A,B,C**

The first algorithm I though about is to filter and keep the darkest pixels, aka the pixels with lower values among input A,B,C.A boolean can do that :

```
gdal_calc.py -A hillshades_A.tmp.tif  -B hillshades_B.tmp.tif -C hillshades_C.tmp.tif --outfile=./hillshades_xl.tmp.tif \
   --calc="(A*(A<=B)*(A<=C)+ B*(B<A)*(B<=C)+ C*(C<A)*(C<B))"
```

The area dominated by shadows now make up more than the opposite side of one central lignt, it been increase by 40⁰ on each side. Not as the link provided, this current algorithm seems to lost too much the enlighten area.

Angle of `315±30⁰` (smaller angle variation) rather that current `315±40⁰` would do nicer.

The diagram below is a the basis of the equation. It shows light sources A, B, C, and the Boolean comparisons for pixels values A, B, C in each part. Equality lines need a special attention to be included into the Boolean. The median lines have value `221` for the perpendicular light source. Think about **areas of influence**, the closest source of light is the main influence, and the farest the weakest influence.

[image]

#### **Keep extremes values for A,B,C**

An other Boolean algorithm could be to keep the most extreme values, both the darkest and the whitest pixels. The following diagram helps to thing about the Boolean formula. For each sixth of the circle, it identifies the value to keep from A,B,C, and a Boolean to select the triangular area plus the clockwise equality line, and **only that**. It gives (from top and clockwise) :

```
--calc="A*(A>B)*(A>=C) + C*(C>A)*(A>=221) + B*(C>A)*(C>=221) + A*(A<B)*(B<=221) + C*(B>A)*(A<=221) + B*(B>A)*(C<=221)"
```

[image]

If the angles variations is not too important, it could give good results.

#### **Other Booleans**

You may create more complex Boolean to cover the whole circles using any combination the border segments. It stays important that only **one value** out of A,B,C is kept for one segment.

#### Multiply

I made [several failled attempts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146689/) to `multiply` pixels values without a proven formula nor final success.
@Radouxju pointed out that `(a*b*c)^(1/3)` (GEOMETRIC mean) instead of the ARITHMETIC mean `(a*b*c)/(255*255)` may work.  Geometric mean is lower or equal to arithmetic mean, which accentuates the darkness of shaded areas. **I haven't tested it yet.**

Comment: I tried to sum up my conceptual learning on composite and how someone could custom it. The real formula for "multiply" stays unknown to me.

Comment: Why not just multiply the values and rescale the results?

Comment: Haven't tried! Which formula would do it, `(A*B*C)/(255*255)` ?

Comment: That would be a good start :-).

Comment: I may miss something with numpy, the whole output of `--calc="(A*B*C)/(255*255)"` is black px=0

Comment: You might be using integer arithmetic or maybe you have a bug in the program. You can easily check for yourself by looking at values for a single cell. For instance, suppose three hillshaded values at one cell are 100, 125, and 150.  Then A\*B\*C/255^2 = 28.8351, which will round to 29--and that is obviously not zero.

Comment: Doing a `gdal_calc.py -A hillshades_A.tmp.tif -B hillshades_B.tmp.tif -C hillshades_C.tmp.tif --outfile=./hillshades_composite.tif --calc="A*B*C/(221*221)"` foolowed by 4 `
$gdallocationinfo ./hillshades_X.tif 10 10 -valonly` I get `222`, `224`, `220`, `0` for files *A.tif, *B.tif, *C.tif and *composite.tif. Path to my input files checked. Result should be `168.2454`.

Comment: @whuber: Unfortunatelly, gdal is not an unicorn. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146689/

Comment: isn't "multiply" using the GEOMETRIC mean instead of the ARITHMETIC mean. (a*b*c)^(1/3). Geometric mean is lower or equal to arithmetic mean, which accentuates the darkness of shaded areas.

Comment: Doesn't works ! http://i.stack.imgur.com/AEpkj.jpg :D

Answer (score 0):

[Gdal_calc](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html)'s numpy seems to have [more operators](http://openforistools.wikispot.org/gdal_calc) :

```
+ addition 
- subtraction 
/ division 
* multiplication 
= equals to 
< less than 
> larger than 
! not equal to 
? if clause 
M maximum of two values 
m minimum of two values 
B bit level operator
```

I haven't found clear and proper examples for how the exotic operators should be used. If you have something, feel free to share.

Answer (score 0):

A tool that can do this (among others) is the Sky-View Factor Based Visualization (http://iaps.zrc-sazu.si/en/svf#v). Calculate several parameters of a terrain.
Is damn good.